# Breaking out of a critical region (but not a parallel loop) in OpenMP

Tags: c, loops, openmp

I am running nested for loop, with the outer one parallelised, and I am wanting to break the inner loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(found, i, j)
  for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
    found = 0;
    for (j=0;j<count;j++) {
      if (isFound(i,j)) {
        #pragma omp critical
        if (isFound(i,j)) {
          found = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    functionX(found);
  }
```

As far as I understand, there is no problem with this functionally, but it is not allowed to compile. Is there a workaround for this?

Edit: compile error as requested:

```
error: "break" branches to or from an OpenMP structured block are illegal
            break;
            ^

compilation aborted for file.c (code 2)
make: *** [file.o] Error 2
```

Comment: If you want answers about compilation errors/warnings it would help a lot if you told us what the compiler says. Your code compiled for me at least after declaring the functions and variables (no idea whether it would run or not).

Comment: Thanks, forgot about that. Has been edited.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `cancel` construct, introduced in OpenMP 4.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the cancel construct, and the documentation is slightly confusing. If i have a `pragma omp cancel for` will it break the for loop, or the outermost 'pragma omp parallel for' ?

Comment: Do you really need to break the loop early? What if you change each `isFound(i,j)` to be `!found && isFound(i,j)` (and then remove the `break`)?

Comment: My aim is to break the for loop, early; that would still mean the code runs through the loop and fails at the if statement each time. However, that has  given me the idea to try an "implicit break" i.e. replace `break` with `j=count`

Comment: I was assuming `isFound()` was doing an expensive compute, so bypassing it would be sufficient. If `count` itself is large enough to want to break the loop early, you may need to investigate what `omp` offers in terms of thread cancellation.